# Im creating my survey form in codepen and I did put the "required" attribute but it still saying that there is no validation error

Tags: html, survey, codepen, validationerror

[This is my template](https://codepen.io/lucasdelrue/pen/NWXWbJv)

I can't pass the challenge because it says "Inside the form element, I am required to enter my name in a field with id="name". If I do not enter a name I will see an HTML5 validation error"

I have tried putting it exactly like another survey form I found but it still did not work.

```
<div>
  <header class="header">
   <h1 id="title">Airplane Magazine</h1>
     <p id="description">This will get you signed to our airplane    news and update magazine</p> 
  </header>
  </div>
     <form id="survey-form">
       <div class="forms">
         <label id="name" for="name">Name</label>
         <input 
             type="text"
             name="name"
             id="name"
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Enter Your Name"
             type="submit"
             required
                ></input>
       </div>
       <div class="forms">
         <label id="email" for="email">Email</label>
         <input 
              type="email"
              id="email"
              class="form-control"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter your Email"
              required
                ></input>
       </div>
       <div class="forms">
         <label id="number" for="number">Age<span class="clue">(optional)</span></label>
         <input 
               type="number"
               name="age"
               id="number"
               min="16"
               max="99"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="age"
                ></input>
               
        </div>
         
    
      </form>
```

Comment: The only input with `type="submit"` also has `type="text"` and so there is no way to submit the form.

Comment: I deleted the type="text" and it stil does not work

Comment: Don't delete the `type="text"` because then you can't type into it, and it is asking for the user's name! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Your form has no submit button. The only input with `type="submit"` also has `type="text"` and so there is no way to submit the form.

  Solution: **Just add a submit button (`<input type="submit">`) to the end of your form, before the closing tag, and remove the `type="submit"` from the first input field.**
- Also I noticed you have specified an input field as such :- `<input ... "required">`

  Solution: **Change the `"required"` to `required="true"` in order for it to work properly.**

I did exactly that in the CodePen you provided and it works. An error is shown if I try to leave the input fields blank.

Comment: I think I did everything you said but it still won't pass the challenge

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe you could upload a screen recording of what happens to a link? Because I tried it again and for me, it works. I opened your updated version of the codepen and again, it works for me. And what do you mean by *pass the challenge*?

Comment: I was using safari then I moved too google and I won't work again

Comment: Im doing the freecodecamp survey form and this is the error its giving me " Inside the form element, I am required to enter my name in a field with id="name". If I do not enter a name I will see an HTML5 validation error."

Comment: Well your form does do that; maybe try to play around to see if it is looking for something specific. For instance try and replace `required="true"` with just `required`. Make sure it is not encased in quotes.

Comment: I tried that an its still not working I really don't understand what else could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe there is some other requirement

Comment: I will continue to see but still thank you for the help